# Why is Linux's sendfile() incompatible with /dev/zero?

Tags: c++, linux

why is [sendfile](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) incompatible with /dev/zero ? why does this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int f1 = fileno(tmpfile());
    int devzero = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
    if(f1 < 0 || devzero < 0){
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open files");
    }
    ssize_t sent = sendfile(f1, devzero, 0, 1);
    std::cout << "sent " << sent << " bytes. errno " << errno << " strerror " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

consistently output

```
sent -1 bytes. errno 22 strerror Invalid argument
```

?

Comment: I see the answer to this question in `sendfile`'s manual page that you linked to. See the 2nd to the last paragraph in "DESCRIPTION".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "The in_fd argument must correspond to a file which supports mmap(2)-like  operations" ? But `/dev/zero` does support `mmap`.

Comment: What led you to believe that, @NateEldredge? A sample test program, literally `int fd=open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR); mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 0, fd, 0);`shows the `mmap` call failing according to strace.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you have to use MAP_SHARED flag, then it will succeed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/vjdv99Kfv).  Your program seems to have forgotten `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`.  mmap'ing `/dev/zero` was the standard way to map anonymous memory before `MAP_ANONYMOUS` was invented.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik mapping `/dev/zero` is part of an ancient ritual for sharing memory (that came from BSD Unix).

Comment: It is an unsupported case not documented as such (a.k.a. "bug"). `/dev/zero` (like most character devices) does not implement the `sendpage` op.

Answer (score 2):

/dev/zero is a special file. It doesn’t represent an on disk file.

From sendfile documentation:

```
The in_fd argument must correspond to a file which supports mmap(2)-like operations (i.e., it cannot be a socket).
...
EINVAL Descriptor is not valid or locked, or an mmap(2)-like operation is not available for in_fd, or count is negative.
EINVAL out_fd has the O_APPEND flag set.  This is not currently supported by sendfile().
```

These section of kernel source is reporting the error:

```
if (unlikely(out->f_flags & O_APPEND))
        return -EINVAL;
ret = rw_verify_area(WRITE, out, opos, len);
```

I performed some testing. Reading from a tmpfile(), a regular file, and /dev/zero works. Writing to a regular file works, but writing to /dev/zero fails one of those checks (O_APPEND permissions or rw_verify_area() ).

Comment: Yeah, but `/dev/zero` does support `mmap(2)`, and nobody said "on disk" was a requirement.  Presumably there is some internal piece that it is missing, and so "unsupported" is probably the right answer, but I don't think it's obvious from the docs.